# how to make a twitter-bootsrap popover on an HTML image map

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a website, in the website i haven an image with an image map.

I am stuck on this point, the popover is working perfectly in an  tag but not in the  tag. does anyone know how to get the twitter-bootstrap popover work on an image map?

I think it has someting to do with this line: `$('#example').tooltip(options)` [tooltip exaple](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips)

[the twitter-bootstrap pover](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)

Thanks (i hope my English is understandable)

Comment: in 2012's web development the cases where an image-map is justifiable are very narrow.

Comment: so what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: I guess your case could be a legitimate use for image-maps, hard to tell without more information. That said, you can make your image the background of a div containing several absolute positioned anchors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn your image map into something like (fill the `...px` with actual dimensions):

```
<div id="#map" style="position:relative;width:...px;height:...px;background-image:...">
    <a id="map-link-1" href="/path/url/for/target/or/#"
        style="position:absolute;top:...px;left:...px;width:...px;height:...px">&nbsp;</a>
    <a id="map-link-2" href="/path/url/for/target/or/#"
        style="position:absolute;top:...px;left:...px;width:...px;height:...px">&nbsp;</a>
    ...
</div>
```

Then deal with the anchors like you are used to.

Comment: i will try it out but i am starting to learn html, so i didn't used anchors before...

Comment: i got it (document.getElementById("thing1").coords); but how do i get the x1,y1 from the .coords??

Comment: I was trying to do something similar with map areas and had a lot of problems with FF and IE (only worked in Chrome). This approach worked well. Thanks

Comment: How does this work with responsive images? Wouldn't the coordinates break as soon as the image is resized?

Comment: For responsive behavior you may consider using `%` instead of `px`.